# Calendar getDisplayName to return utf-8

Tags: java, utf-8, httprequest, encode

I use a method to get the display name of a month according to `Locale.getDefault()`

```
private String getLocaleMonthString(Date date){
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
return cal.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.SHORT, Locale.getDefault());
```

I send this result in an `http request`, the `http request` encoding is `UTF-8`

And the display name is ??? for some languages even though in my log it is correct.

The problem is the `string` is not created with the right encoding, but I dont see where I can change/set encoding in this small piece of code?

EDIT:

added the code for the httppost as requested

```
    Date date = null;
    HttpPost post = null;
    MultipartEntityBuilder builder = null;
    builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    builder.setCharset(Charset.forName(HTTP.UTF_8));
    date = getDateFromFile(file,0);
    String localeMonth = getLocaleMonthString(date);
    post = new HttpPost(url);
    builder.addPart("filePath", new StringBody(file.getAbsolutePath(),ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));
    builder.addPart("date", new StringBody(getISODate(date), ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));
    builder.addPart("localeMonth", new StringBody(localeMonth, ContentType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED));
    builder.addPart("type", new StringBody("video", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));

    HttpResponse response = null;
```

Comment: Strings do not have an encoding by themselves. Encoding happens when the characters in the string are converted to bytes (in the HTTP response).

Comment: "And the display name is ??? for some languages" ... for which languages, which fields/styles and on which browsers does this happen?

Comment: the language is hebrew, on firefox. fields/styles? Defaults I guess

Comment: String cannot be in incorrect encoding. The problem is surely not in this code, but somewhere later when you write this string into servlet `OutputStream`.

Comment: Can you post the code which creates/sends the HTTP request containing the month-string?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a unit test for `getLocaleMonthString` that does something like:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(new Date(1433367642000L));
assertEquals("\u05D9\u05D5\u05E0", cal.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.SHORT, new Locale("he")));
```

... where `1433367642000L` is now and `\u05D9\u05D5\u05E0` is `יונ` or "Jun". Or `Calendar.LONG` and `\u05D9\u05D5\u05E0\u05D9` for June `יוני`.

So per the other comments, there's nothing wrong with getting the properly-encoded characters from the date, since `String`s don't deal with encoding.  You need to check how you are sending this in your outbound HTTP request, to ensure that the encoding is properly handled there.  That code is not visible in your question.